# Angular Js - Prefill the Search with values from input

Tags: angularjs

i'm quite new to Angular JS so this is probably a easy question to answer.

I have the following code. Which displays a JSON Array with several Locations, descriptions and so on. Outputting the whole thing works. And searching the field place works also .

However as I have different pages, where I want to output only lets say all locations were place is "Canada". I thought i could just use "Canada" as `value="Canada"` in my input with `ng-model="search.place"` to output only places in "Canada" . However that does not work. It seems like ng-model causes the value to disappear. Typing in "Canada" in the input however works like a charm.

How can i overcome this? ;)

```
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
<div class="topcoat-list__container">
   <input ng-model="search.place" >

  <ul class="topcoat-list">
    <li class="topcoat-list__item" hm-tap="open(myApp.item_id)" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search ">
      <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
      {{item.description}}

    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: This is my Controller:

```
myApp.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope, Restangular) {


// Fetch all objects from the local JSON (see app/models/myApp.js)
$scope.items = Restangular.all('item').getList();



});
```

**EDIT2**
I found an answer:

```
$scope.items = $filter("filter")($scope.items, {place: "Canada"});
```

This works and accepts also multiple parameters as {place: "Canada", price: 10}

Answer (score 0):

$scope.search.place="Canada"; in the controller should do it.

Take a look at the [4th step of the AngularJS tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04) to understand the two way databinding.

Comment: See above my controller. Im using Restangular which makes it a little more complicated i guess :D    Just adding `$scope.search.place="Canada";` doesnt work.

Comment: I have to add: $scope.search="Canada" works, but of course on all fields not only on place